# Nullpointerexception using ExpandableListActivity

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, expandablelistview

I want to use the `ExpandableListActivity` class but don't want to extend my class from that class. However I want to extend my class from `ActionBarActivity` and use `ExpandableListActivity`. When I extend my class from `ExpandableListActivity`everything works great.

I tried it with this:

```
public class GestureAnyWhere extends ActionBarActivity   {

ExpandableListActivity ex = new ExpandableListActivity ();


ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener liste_schritt1_Listener = new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener () {
    @Override
    public boolean onChildClick ( ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id ) {

        Toast.makeText ( getApplicationContext (), " " + childPosition, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show ();
        return false;
    }
};
```

...

```
layoutElementeAnordnen ();
```

..

```
private void layoutElementeAnordnen () {

    TextView schritt1 = ( TextView ) findViewById ( R.id.schritt1 );
    schritt1.setTextSize ( 14 );
    schritt1.setTextColor ( getResources ().getColor ( R.color.rot ) );


    // Ausklappbares ListView
    // ExpandableListView liste_schritt1 = (ExpandableListView)findViewById ( R.id.list);
    // funktioniert nicht, da die ExpandableListView keine neue ID bekommen darf






ExpandableListView liste_schritt1 = ex.getExpandableListView ();
```

But on the line `ExpandableListView liste_schritt1 = ex.getExpandableListView ();` there is an `NullpointerException`:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1939)
        at android.app.ExpandableListActivity.ensureList(ExpandableListActivity.java:273)
        at android.app.ExpandableListActivity.getExpandableListView(ExpandableListActivity.java:257)
        at de.gestureanywhere.GestureAnyWhere.layoutElementeAnordnen(GestureAnyWhere.java:77)
        at de.gestureanywhere.GestureAnyWhere.onCreate(GestureAnyWhere.java:61)
```

The corresponding part of the layout file:

```
<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:groupIndicator="@null"
    android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll">
</ExpandableListView>
```

I think it's because I create a new `ExpandableListActivity` object with this: `ExpandableListActivity ex = new ExpandableListActivity ();`. And then `ExpandableListView liste_schritt1 = ex.getExpandableListView ();`is null.

As I mentioned everything works great when I extend from `ExpandableListActivity`. Because I extend now from `ActionBarActivity` I just modified my code with these points:

- `ExpandableListActivity ex = new ExpandableListActivity ();` as new line
- `ExpandableListView liste_schritt1 = ex.getExpandableListView ();` (before: `ExpandableListView liste_schritt1 = getExpandableListView ();`

Thanks a lot for helping

Comment: make a breakpoint at `GestureAnyWhere.java:77` to see what is null

Comment: The 'ExpandableListView liste_schritt1 = ex.getExpandableListView ();' is null. That's because I create a new 'ExpandableListActivity' object with: 'ExpandableListActivity ex = new ExpandableListActivity ();'.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using `ExpandableListActivity` as class field? You can just call `(ExpandableListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list)` from your main Activity to get list instead of `getExpandableListView()`.

Answer (score 0):

In case of ExpandableListActivity we must have 3 layouts:

- First one containing the main `ExpandableListView` view.
- Second one for the groups.
- Third one for the children (detail rows).

you possibly missing one of the above